# C lang: Segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Recently I have been learning C from K&R's book, and then I came across an error. From what I know a segmentation fault is something to do with the memory, but it is not explained in the book. If you could please look at my code and explain what a segmentation fault is, and how this error came to be in my code. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 256

int main () {
  int c, ndigit[10], i, d, e;
  char str[MAXLINE];
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
      if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
          ++ndigit[c - '0'];}
  for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      for (d = 0; d < ndigit[i]; d++)
          str[d] = '*';
    str[d] = '\0';
    printf("%d: %s\n",i,str);
    for (e = 0; e <= MAXLINE; e++)
      str[e] = '\0';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (e = 0; e <= MAXLINE; e++)` should be `for (e = 0; e < MAXLINE; e++)`. (although the answer gives an even more serious error). Use a debugger to find where the problem lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't initializing `ndigit` to zero, it's an array of garbage values that you then increment. It's likely `ndigit`'s values are quite large, causing you to access `str` with a very large index, overflowing the bounds of the `str` array into invalid memory regions. The operating system sees you trying to access invalid memory regions and issues a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), killing your program.

Also, as Jean-François Fabre points out, your `for`-loop should go to `< MAXLINE` because the last valid index for `str` is `MAXLINE - 1`.

And as mszymborski points out, you likely want a newline (`'\n'`) at the end of your print statement.

Comment: And a newline when printing would be nice, too.

Comment: Thank you @Cornstalks. That was so stupid of me, I must have not had my coffee this morning. The program runs as expected now

Comment: It's worth adding that for debugging problems like that `Valgrind` works really well. I believe it intercepts memory access instructions and is able to pinpoint the issue with a deadly accuracy.